# How to order in sql like 123ABC

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I need to order column like:

```
1 
2 
10 
100 
Ape
Cat
Elephant
Whatever
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close with:

```
order by (case when col >= '1' and col < '9999999' then 1 else 2 end),
         col
```

This has the advantage of working on almost any database.  However, there are database-specific solutions that might be simpler.

EDIT:

If you want the numbers that start with digits to be sorted numerically, then you can use:

```
order by (case when col >= '1' and col < '9999999' then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when col >= '1' and col < '9999999' then len(col) end),
         col
```

Note that some databases use `length()` instead of `len()`.

Comment: It was ordered like A BAT CAT 1 100 1000 2. So it is not working this way.

Comment: @СергейМасяев . . . There was a typo in the `else` clause.

Comment: could you please change code to order by (case when col >= '1' and col < '9999999' then 1 else 2 end),
         col + 0

Comment: @СергейМасяев . . . No.  You haven't specified the database in your question and that would result in a run-time exception in most databases.

Answer (score 0):

select name from points  order  by
(case when name>='0' and name < '999999' then 1 else 2 end),
CAST(name as INT),
(case when name >= '1' and name < '9999999' then length(name) end) desc,
name asc